# Failed booting after ubuntu installation

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I installed ubuntu by overwriting my windows. After successful installation, i restarted the pc, removed the live disk and got a black screen. 
After several research with too much mumbo jumbo, i resorted to running a `sudo fdisk -l and sudo gdisk -l` which gave this

```
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.8 GiB, 1905045504 bytes, 3720792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 91 MiB, 95408128 bytes, 186344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 34.6 MiB, 36216832 bytes, 70736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 140.7 MiB, 147496960 bytes, 288080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 2.3 MiB, 2355200 bytes, 4600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 14.5 MiB, 15208448 bytes, 29704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 3.7 MiB, 3878912 bytes, 7576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc6e52d91

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             2048    1026047    1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          1026048 1543921663 1542895616 735.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       1543923710 1953523711  409600002 195.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1543923712 1575172095   31248384  14.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6  *    1590798336 1591382015     583680   285M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda7       1591384064 1953523711  362139648 172.7G 83 Linux

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.




Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 GiB, 3959422976 bytes, 7733248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0028fccc

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 7733247 7731200  3.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk -l
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Problem opening -l for reading! Error is 2.
The specified file does not exist!
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 

What do i do, help
```

Comment: You still show Windows NTFS partitions. Drive is MBR(msdos) partitioned which is required if booting Windows in BIOS boot mode. But it looks like you forced UEFI boot onto MBR (UEFI recommends gpt) drive. Windows also requires gpt if using Windows in UEFI boot mode. Converting drive from MBR to gpt will erase it. Do you still want Windows boot? If so move boot flag back to sda1, and use Boot-Repair to convert Ubuntu to BIOS boot. Or reinstall Ubuntu in BIOS mode. But new systems are UEFI and generally better to then use UEFI boot.